# key error 'Negative review' while benchmarking Dask vs pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, machine-learning, dask

after two sentiment analysis, I need to do a Dasklib vs Pandas comparison in a benchmark way. I though I had it until I ran into the error "KeyError: 'Negative_Review'"

This is my code:

```
# %%
import sys
sys.path.append('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/py ')

import pandas as pd
import dask.dataframe as ddf
import time
import pymongo
from pymongo import MongoClient
# %%
# Mongo DB init
client = pymongo.MongoClient("mongodb://localhost", 27017)
db = client['Hotel_Test']
collection = db['collection']

# %%
# DASK

def run_dask():
    #read data
    df_dask = ddf.read_csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/Hotel_Reviews_Cleaned.csv')
    df_dask = df_dask.dropna()
    df_dask = df_dask.sample(frac = 0.05)

    #devide dataset into negative and positive sets and assign correct boolean rating
    negative = df_dask['Negative_Review']
    positive = df_dask['Positive_Review']

    #additional cleaning
    negative = negative.drop_duplicates()
    positive = positive.drop_duplicates()

    negative = negative.to_frame()
    positive = positive.to_frame()

    cleaned_negative_reviews = negative['Negative_Review']
    cleaned_positive_reviews = positive['Positive_Review']

    cleaned_negative_reviews['rating'] = 0
    cleaned_positive_reviews['rating'] = 1

    #write negative and positive reviews to csv files
    cleaned_negative_reviews.to.csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/dask_negative_reviews.csv')
    cleaned_positive_reviews.to.csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/dask_positive_reviews.csv')

    print('Dask done')

# %%
# PANDAS

def run_pandas():
    #read data
    df = pd.read_csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/Hotel_Reviews_Cleaned.csv')
    df = df.dropna()
    df = df.sample(frac=0.05)

    #devide dataset into negative and positive sets and assign correct boolean rating
    negative = pd.DataFrame(df['Negative_Review'])
    positive =  pd.DataFrame(df['Positive_Review'])

    #additional cleaning
    reviews_negative = negative[negative["review"] != "No Negative"]
    reviews_positive = positive[positive["review"] != "No Positive"]

    cleaned_negative_reviews = reviews_negative['review']
    cleaned_positive_reviews = reviews_positive['review']

    cleaned_negative_reviews['rating'] = 0
    cleaned_positive_reviews['rating'] = 1

    #write negative and positive reviews to csv files
    cleaned_negative_reviews.to.csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/pandas_negative_reviews.csv')
    cleaned_positive_reviews.to.csv('/Users/rokayadarai/Desktop/Coding/DataSets/pandas_positive_reviews.csv')

    print('Pandas done')
    
    # %%
    # denfine benchmark
def benchmark(function, function_name):
        start = time.time()
        function()
        end = time.time()
        print('{0} seconds for {1}'.format((end - start), function_name))
# %%
benchmark(run_dask, 'dataframe dask')
benchmark(run_pandas, 'dataframe pandas')

# %%
```

and this is the error Traceback:

```
KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2894             try:
-> 2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/index.pyx in pandas._libs.index.IndexEngine.get_loc()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

pandas/_libs/hashtable_class_helper.pxi in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item()

KeyError: 'Negative_Review'

The above exception was the direct cause of the following exception:

KeyError                                  Traceback (most recent call last)
~/Desktop/Coding/py /DASK_vs_PANDAS.py in 
----> 85 benchmark(run_dask, 'dataframe dask')
      86 benchmark(run_pandas, 'dataframe pandas')

~/Desktop/Coding/py /DASK_vs_PANDAS.py in benchmark(function, function_name)
      2 def benchmark(function, function_name):
      3     start = time.time()
----> 4     function()
      5     end = time.time()
      6     print('{0} seconds for {1}'.format((end - start), function_name))

~/Desktop/Coding/py /DASK_vs_PANDAS.py in run_dask()
      24 
      25     #devide dataset into negative and positive sets and assign correct boolean rating
---> 26     negative = df_dask['Negative_Review']
     27     positive = df_dask['Positive_Review']
     28 

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/dask/dataframe/core.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   3535 
   3536             # error is raised from pandas
-> 3537             meta = self._meta[_extract_meta(key)]
   3538             dsk = partitionwise_graph(operator.getitem, name, self, key)
   3539             graph = HighLevelGraph.from_collections(name, dsk, dependencies=[self])

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/frame.py in __getitem__(self, key)
   2900             if self.columns.nlevels > 1:
   2901                 return self._getitem_multilevel(key)
-> 2902             indexer = self.columns.get_loc(key)
   2903             if is_integer(indexer):
   2904                 indexer = [indexer]

~/opt/anaconda3/lib/python3.8/site-packages/pandas/core/indexes/base.py in get_loc(self, key, method, tolerance)
   2895                 return self._engine.get_loc(casted_key)
   2896             except KeyError as err:
-> 2897                 raise KeyError(key) from err
   2898 
   2899         if tolerance is not None:

KeyError: 'Negative_Review'
```

The error occurs as soon as I run the last cell. Could someone tell me please what I'm doing wrong?

My dataset does have the column 'Negative_Review'. See screenshot below.
[Click here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/6u2TE.png)

Comment: It seems like your dataframe doesn't have "Negative_Review" column. Are you certain it's there?

Comment: Yes, I'm positive. I'll attach a screenshot of the data 'info' to my question!

Comment: Can you also confirm this by printing `df_dask.columns` right after you import the data as a dask dataframe?  Maybe something went pear-shaped when reading the csv.

Comment: It doesn't actually print anything.. That's weird right?

Comment: It is odd. Seems like there might be issues when csv is loaded. Try specifying columns manually when loading using `columns` argument to `read_csv`

Comment: I asked a new question, because I ran into a new error! Thank you for helping me so far!